# java rest client for mixed parameter forms

Tags: java, xml, rest, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have a rest method which takes two parameters one map parameter, and the other is a String variable

```
 @POST
 public returnValue postMethod(  Map<String,String>  anotherMap,
                       @QueryParam("name") String name    
                ) {}
```

It is easy to pass each parameter by itself where 
the map parameter can be passed using XML as follow :

```
 ClientResponse response = service
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .post(ClientResponse.class, map).getEntity(ClientResponse.class).
```

and the QueryParam can be passed as usual :

```
service.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
             .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                         .post(ClientResponse.class, f)
```

where f is a Form ,

the question is : how  can we pass both parameter together from the same Java client ?

Answer (score 0):

So you're asking - how do I `POST` a `Map` **and** pass a `String` as a `query param`? With sending and receiving XML.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
ClientBuilder clientBuilder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
//Do some building code
Client client = clientBuilder.build();
WebTarget target =  client.target(endPoint);
Response response = target
  .queryParam("name", "value")
  .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE)
  .post(Entity.entity(map), MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
```

Hope this helps.